# Index not seeing from search head SPLUNK

Tags: splunk

I've been indexing from de web UI with Splunk Enterprise, but I realise that I can Index data from Add Data into a custom index in another box. My custom index reside in another box, when I tried to add data into that custom index from my search head, the index don´t appear.

Someone can give me an approax?

Regards.

[Add data into custom index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5sjUg.png)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you started with a standalone Splunk set up (Search Head combined with an indexer) and stored the data on that original standalone Splunk machine. You now created a secondary indexer and want to create an index on that machine..

So my first question is why?

If your wanting high availability, then you can cluster 3 machines and have an index cluster. If you want to go this route, you can turn your standalone machine into an indexer and add a new search head.

Comment: Hi, I started with a Search Head in one machine and indexer in another, I've created a custom indexer in the indexer machine, but when I want to add data from the search head that also works as deployment server, I cannot see my custom index witch resides on indexer machine. The cluster machines hasn´t enable yet.

Comment: How did you create the index on the indexer? Did you create a new entry in `indexes.conf` on the indexer or do you have the Web UI enabled on the indexer and created the index that way? 

If you did it through `indexes.conf` which one did you edit? It sounds like a precedence issue

Comment: yeah, I've created  by deployment an app from the deployment server (search head also), to the indexer.